# HMVC Code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing, codeigniter-hmvc

I have a local XAMPP setup, i developed a nice app with HMVC(wireddesignz) codeigniter. Everything works perfectly. When i upload it to my server i get 404 errors when i try to load any of the modules. I can load the default welcome with no problems. and the 404s are generated by Codeigntier not the server.

Only route i use is the default.

```
$route['default_controller'] = "users/login";
```

I have turned logging on level 4 and receive not errors other than a timezone error, that has now been corrected and did not help.

Any insight?

Comment: maybe check your .htaccess with that. or did you tried to put index.php/ before calling your module name?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appeared to be an issue with capitalization, And how xammp on windows handled it and Linux server did not.